# Add Agent with llm-math to a LangChain Expressive Language implementation

Tags: python, langchain

I have this LCEL solution:

```
from langchain.document_loaders.pdf import PyMuPDFLoader
import os
from typing import List, Tuple
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate
from langchain.schema import AIMessage, HumanMessage
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field
from langchain_core.runnables import (
    RunnableParallel,
    RunnableLambda
)
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader, TextLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOllama

from langchain.embeddings import GPT4AllEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Qdrant
from langchain.utils.math import cosine_similarity

load_dotenv()

# Define a dictionary to map file extensions to their respective loaders
loaders = {
    '.pdf': PyMuPDFLoader,
    '.txt': TextLoader
}

# Define a function to create a DirectoryLoader for a specific file type
def create_directory_loader(file_type, directory_path):
    return DirectoryLoader(
        path=directory_path,
        glob=f"**/*{file_type}",
        loader_cls=loaders[file_type],
        show_progress=True,
        use_multithreading=True
    )


dirpath = os.environ.get('DOCS_DIRECTORY')
pdf_loader = create_directory_loader('.pdf', dirpath)
txt_loader = create_directory_loader('.txt', dirpath)

pdfs = pdf_loader.load()
texts = txt_loader.load()

full_text = ''
for paper in texts:
    full_text = full_text + paper.page_content

for paper in pdfs:
    full_text = full_text + paper.page_content

full_text = " ".join(l for l in full_text.splitlines() if l)

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=1024,
    chunk_overlap=100
)

document_chunks = text_splitter.create_documents([full_text])

embeddings = GPT4AllEmbeddings()

url = 'http://0.0.0.0:6333'
qdrant = Qdrant.from_documents(
    documents=document_chunks,
    embedding=embeddings,
    url=url,
    collection_name="v2_local",
    prefer_grpc=True,
    force_recreate=True
)

# do two different kinda searches using
# different algoriths, then submit both combined
# as context.
def _custom_retriever(inputs):
    question = inputs["question"]
    sim_search = qdrant.similarity_search(query=question, k=2)
    marg_search = qdrant.max_marginal_relevance_search(query=question, k=5)
    combined_retrieved_context = sim_search[0].page_content + \
        marg_search[0].page_content
    return combined_retrieved_context


# Ollama
ollama_llm = os.environ.get('MODEL_NAME') or "llama2:chat"
model = ChatOllama(model=ollama_llm, temperature=0.9)

def prepare_prompts(prompts):
    prompt_templates = [item.prompt for item in prompts]
    prompt_embeddings = embeddings.embed_documents(prompt_templates)
    return [prompt_embeddings, prompt_templates]


def prompt_router(input):
    prompt_embeddings, prompt_templates = prepare_prompts(input["prompt"])
    query_embedding = embeddings.embed_query(input["question"])
    similarity = cosine_similarity([query_embedding], prompt_embeddings)[0]
    most_similar = prompt_templates[similarity.argmax()]
    return PromptTemplate.from_template(most_similar)


def _format_chat_history(chat_history: List[List[str]]) -> List:
    buffer = []
    for human, ai in chat_history:
        buffer.append(HumanMessage(content=f'[INST]{human}[/INST]'))
        buffer.append(AIMessage(content=ai))
    return buffer

class PromptItem(BaseModel):
    name: str
    prompt: str


class ChatHistory(BaseModel):
    chat_history: List[Tuple[str, str]] = Field(..., extra={
                                                "widget": {"type": "chat"}})
    question: str
    prompt: List[PromptItem]


_inputs = RunnableParallel(
    {
        "context": _custom_retriever,
        "question": lambda x: x["question"],
        "chat_history": lambda x: _format_chat_history(x["chat_history"]),
        "prompt": lambda x: x["prompt"]
    }
).with_types(input_type=ChatHistory)


chain = _inputs | RunnableLambda(prompt_router) | model | StrOutputParser()
```

It currently works fine, but absolutely terrible with any calculations related questions. I want to include the `llm-math` tool into this chain via agents.

Trying to work my way via using the [agents LCEL example](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/quick_start) here even fails with [ValueError](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/15634) using their default cookbook example

End results I'm trying to achieve is add the ability to handle mathematical calculations via an agent tool like `llm-math`, in tandem with the current approach above via the LCEL.

Comment: See the end of my answer below for a new development.

Answer (score 0):

From the [issue/discussion #15634](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/15634) you mention, it would fail on [`langchain-ai/langchain@libs/langchain/langchain/agents/output_parsers/xml.py def parse(self, text: str)`](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/langchain/langchain/agents/output_parsers/xml.py#L31C2-L45)

```py
    def parse(self, text: str) -> Union[AgentAction, AgentFinish]:
        if "</tool>" in text:
            tool, tool_input = text.split("</tool>")
            _tool = tool.split("<tool>")[1]
            _tool_input = tool_input.split("<tool_input>")[1]
            if "</tool_input>" in _tool_input:
                _tool_input = _tool_input.split("</tool_input>")[0]
            return AgentAction(tool=_tool, tool_input=_tool_input, log=text)
        elif "<final_answer>" in text:
            _, answer = text.split("<final_answer>")
            if "</final_answer>" in answer:
                answer = answer.split("</final_answer>")[0]
            return AgentFinish(return_values={"output": answer}, log=text)
        else:
            raise ValueError
```

That means the `ValueError` in the `parse` method from `langchain-ai/langchain`'s `xml.py` file is triggered when the input text does not conform to the expected XML structure that the method is designed to handle. Specifically:

- Missing `<tool>` and `<final_answer>` tags: the method expects either `</tool>` or `<final_answer>` tags in the input text. If neither of these tags is present, the method won't be able to correctly classify the input as either an `AgentAction` or an `AgentFinish`. This situation would lead to the `else` branch, raising a `ValueError`.
- Improperly closed tags:  if the tags `<tool>`, `<tool_input>`, or `<final_answer>` are not properly closed (e.g., missing the corresponding closing tag like `</tool>`), the string splitting operations will not work as expected. This could result in incomplete or incorrect parsing of the tool name, tool input, or the final answer.
- Incorrect tag nesting or order: if the tags are not correctly nested or ordered (for example, if `<tool_input>` appears before `<tool>`), the string splitting based on these tags will produce incorrect results, leading to parsing errors.
- Extraneous content outside tags: any content outside the expected tags can also cause issues. The method assumes that the text string is formatted in a very specific way, with clear demarcations for tool names, inputs, and final answers. Any deviation from this format can result in parsing failure.

Your code does not seem to interact with XML structures or parse XML strings in the same way.
But the error could occur during document loading or text processing if the files are not in the expected format or if there are issues with the document loaders (`PyMuPDFLoader`, `TextLoader`).

The method of concatenating texts from different documents and splitting lines could lead to unexpected results if the documents have special formatting or non-standard line breaks.

The `_custom_retriever` function performs similarity and relevance searches. Errors might occur if the `qdrant` object does not function as expected, for example, if the query does not return the expected results, or if there is an issue with the search algorithms.

So:

- confirm first the ValueError is exactly the one mentioned in [issue/discussion #15634](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/15634)
- if it is, then check the input text, and the XML structure it is supposed to follow.

---

In that same discussion, [Gardner Bickford](https://github.com/gardner) [points out](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/15634#discussioncomment-8092525):

> The example uses claude-2:
>
> ```
> model = ChatAnthropic(model="claude-2")
> ```
>
> I noticed the code above is using `ollama`.
> Given the output parser is having trouble, it could be related to the chat_template of how the model is being called or the format in which it is outputting text.

And:

> Because the open-source models are trained in different ways, any of the models used with `ollama` can have wildly different prompt formats and output can vary.
>
> You can see an example of how a chat template can affect interacting with a [model here](https://huggingface.co/TencentARC/LLaMA-Pro-8B-Instruct/discussions/4#659a645feff07dcf1fa0583e).
>
> If you are using llama 2 chat, then check out [`chat/llama2_chat`](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/chat/llama2_chat).
>
> You may have more success using `llama-cpp-python` instead of `ollama`: [`abetlen/llama-cpp-python#711`](https://github.com/abetlen/llama-cpp-python/pull/711)

[Eugene Yurtsev](https://github.com/eyurtsev) [adds](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/15634#discussioncomment-8104436):

> The XML parser can probably be improved to catch more exceptions and then throw them properly, it'll allow the agent to at least retry the function call again with some feedback about why the call failed.
> But it won't make the agent significantly better even with the parsers fixed, for that, you need a better model.
>
> If you're using OSS models, try to find one that's tuned for function calling. ([Benchmarks](https://langchain-ai.github.io/langchain-benchmarks/notebooks/tool_usage/benchmark_all_tasks.html))

---

[issue 15634](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/15634) mentions, in [Sohan Saldanha](https://github.com/sohanjs111) 's [comment](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/15634#discussioncomment-8250590):

> The error you are seeing is because `XMLAgentOutputParser` is expecting a specific format of input that includes XML tags for the tool, tool_input, and observation. However, the output from the `ChatOllama` model is not in this format, and therefore `XMLAgentOutputParser` is unable to parse it.
>
> I was using `ChatOpenai` instead of `ChatOllama` and experienced the same problem.
>
> I finally got it to work, by returning the log between intermediate_steps tag.
>
> ```
> def convert_intermediate_steps(intermediate_steps):
>     log = ""
>     for action, observation in intermediate_steps:
>         log += (
>             f"<tool>{action.tool}</tool><tool_input>{action.tool_input}</tool_input><observation>{observation}</observation>"
>         )
>     return f"<intermediate_steps>{log}</intermediate_steps>"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations. Will check them all out and give it a try

Comment: Update: None of the fixes work. I've tried using slightly bigger models. Doing exactly as suggested still throws the ValueError. Here's my LangSmith trace: https://smith.langchain.com/public/d4a4a29d-8b5e-4785-8569-f7bd266ee30c/r

Comment: @KhoPhi OK, I hope you will find a solution. Considering the traceback and the context, the issue seems to stem from a mismatch between the expected input format of the `XMLAgentOutputParser` and the actual output format produced by the agent's operation chain, which is what I already mentioned in the answer.